# Trying to define a function in R but it turns out to be object instead

Tags: python, r

im a student who are currently studying R, and my lecturer gives me an assignment from one of the notebooks, here are the question:

We previously defined the generic power function and the instances square and cube this way:

```
power <- function(n) function(x) x^n
square <- power(2)
cube <- power(3)
```

If you instead defined this:

```
power <- function(x, n) x^n
```

How would you then define square and cube?

with the 1st example both power,square,and cube would become a function, that can calculate a vector

with `x= (1,2,3,4,5)`
I tried solving the problem using a various of code combination such as

```
square=power(x,2) # it works, but it creates 'square' as an  object of x^2 instead of being a function,
square=power(,2) # telling me that x has to be defined and cant be empty
square= power(2) # I know it wouldn't work and it says n has to be defined which is... not a surprise
```

The book doesn't gives any example of this and I'm basically out of ideas on how to redefine the function, so any helps would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
power <- function(x, n) x^n

square <- function(x) power(x, 2)
cube <- function(x) power(x, 3)

square(3) # 9
cube(3)   # 27
```

Given the following definition of `x`:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

You can run

```
> square(x)
[1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

And you will receive a numeric vector. If you do

```
square = power(x, 2)
```

You receive the same result. In the first example, `square` is a function. In the second example, `square` is a resulting vector of squares.

Comment: thankyou it works, can u please point out why I have to include the function (x) too? is it just something u use to tell R to turn square into a function instead of an object?

Comment: `function(x)` defines a function. Without it, you just execute `power(x, 1)` once, with it - you create a function that accepts arguments

Comment: i see... thanks for helping, i wish u a nice day sir

Comment: Welcome to the community @ferdinandfisrandapbicez if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Given `power <- function(x, n) x^n`, you should define `square` like below

```
square <- function(x) power(x, 2)
```